# SQL: DATE Type data is returning a DATE TIME VALUE

Tags: sql, laravel

I have an Overtime table with ote_date (DATE) and Employees Table with emp_start_date (DATE). However ote is being return like 01-01-01 00:00:00 rather than plain 01-01-01.

I have the following doctrine query using laravel.

```
return Overtime::select('overtimes.*','overtimes.id as ote_id','first_name','last_name','middle_name','stat.name as stat_name','clt_name','cte_name', 'overtimes.ote_date as test')
    ->leftjoin('users','users.id','=','ote_user_id')
    ->leftjoin('employees','employees.emp_user_id','=','ote_user_id')
    ->leftjoin('clients','clt_id','=','emp_client_id')
    ->leftjoin('client_teams','cte_id','=','emp_client_team_id')
    ->leftjoin('options as stat','stat.id','=','ote_status_id')
    ->where('emp_isactive','=',1)
    ->where('emp_rehire','=',0)
    ->where('ote_date', '>=', 'emp_start_date');
```

Sample output of the query:

```
{"id":22808,"ote_user_id":1294,"ote_reason":"Holiday Premium","ote_date":"2019-08-12 00:00:00","ote_start_time":"21:00:00","ote_end_time":"06:00:00","ote_total_hours":"8.00","ote_status_id":123,"ote_whole_day":1,"created_at":"2019-08-15 12:58:54","created_by":1294,"updated_at":"2019-08-24 03:10:05","modified_by":1669,"deleted_at":null,"ote_id":22808,"first_name":"Dummy","last_name":"Dummy","middle_name":"Autor","stat_name":"Approved","clt_name":"Dummy","cte_name":"Sales Development Representative (SDR)","emp_start_date":"2019-08-12"}
```

As you can see on my data:

"ote_date":"2019-08-12 00:00:00" 
"emp_start_date":"2019-08-12"

They're both DATE types so how come the other one is returning a DATETIME?

Comment: Do you have a migration file for Your Overtime table? What does ote_date look like there?

Answer (score 1):

My first reaction is to think that ote_date **MUST** be defined as a Timestamp column somehow somewhere!?

(BTW, a minor point and unrelated point, but I note that your query doesn't quite match up to your sample output - the last column in the query is "overtimes.ote_date as test" while the last column in the output is "emp_start_date").

I guess you have a catalog query that confirms/demonstrates ote_date is defined as Date?

I haven't encountered the behaviour you describe in any SQL environment previously.